# How to make an horizontal RecyclerView match phone borders and go back to line

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, kotlin, linearlayoutmanager

I am making a list of tags, and I put them in a RecyclerView.

Here is my code :

```
var tagsRv : RecyclerView? = null
tagsRv = binding.tagsRv
tagsRv?.adapter = tagsAdapter

val layoutManager : LinearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
tagsRv?.layoutManager = layoutManager
if (menu.tags.isNotEmpty)
    tagsAdapter.setTags(menu.tags)
```

It does work, but I would like to make this horizontal list go back to the line when it reach the phone border.

Does someone know a magical property that can be add to my var layoutManager, that will do the job ?

Or do I have to make an algorythm to do this by myself ?

If I use bad terms, please give me the right words so I can search by myself.

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT : Here is the part of the layout file corresponding to my RecyclerView :

```css
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout_infos"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.discodery.android.discoderyapp.infos.InfosActivity">

  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

      <!-- More stuff -->

      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/tags_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
    
      <!-- More stuff -->

    </LinearLayout>

  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is a picture :

[image]

The tags are in blue, and they overtake my phone border, and I want them to continue back to the line instead.

This is the expected output :

[image]

Sorry for being hard to understand, I can hardly express my problem.

Comment: please post row layout file

Comment: And please clarify what exactly would you like to get. Some picture would be appreciated.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `SnapHelper` . [Here](https://blog.mindorks.com/using-snaphelper-in-recyclerview-fc616b6833e8) a good tutorial for Snapping Or you can search for it .

Comment: Or GridLayoutManager for placing them in more than 1 row

Comment: Can you post the expected output ? Its quite unclear what exactly you want right now .

Comment: Actually SnapHelper seems to do exactly the same thing I don't want to.
I just posted a picture of the expected output (thanks Kolourpaint)